# SVN stops realizing a directory has a new file, so add on parent folder does not find files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I used to be able to use the tortoiseSVN add on the parent folder o my project and it would find all files new that needed to be added them, give me a list and I could click okay.   Now if I do this it says no new files, and yet I know there are and have to manually goto the file and add it.   Was it a setting change I am unaware of, I am not even sure what the parent down method of adding is called (subdirectories? but the add doesnt give that option) .  This is a WAG I am taking posting here grasping at straws...my project is getting large and remembering all the files I added to the Unity project is getting tedious, not sure what stopped it from working the other way...

Comment: I wonder what dialogue you are trying. “Commit” has a whole range of options to display or hide such files as unversioned, ignore, etc, as does “Check for modifications”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. With TortoiseSVN, you can do not add explicitly new files in WC before commit - TSVN will discover new files for you automatically
2. SVN (TortoiseSVN) will skip files, if they match ignore-pattern (global or local): `svn status`|`svn status --no-ignore` inside folder in question may help you detect such ignored files

Comment: With Tortoise you do not _have_ to add before you commit, but you can if you want.

Comment: that is strange cause if i just commit tortoiseSVN misses the files I just added.... and that is the problem it is no longer discovering the files.  Maybe the ignore did get set different I will double check if i can shut that off in tortoise or tweak it or at least see what it thinks it's doing.

Comment: I want to answer my own question< i realized somehow in my ignore list a * got thrown in there above the folders i really did want to ignore... so I removed that and it seemed to find the non-versioned files and let me add them recursively.  This was a pain to figure out.